# How do I "connect to server" in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, server, remote-access

In versions of Ubuntu prior to 11.10, the file manager had a "connect to server" menu item. Is this functionality present in 11.10? I have used Ubuntu for 6 years. I cannot find it in 11.10.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 5):

From the Desktop (or nautilus window) go to the File menu and select Connect to Server.

You need to have a nautilus window or the desktop selected to see this global menu at the top of screen.